# Array sorting and global variable scope in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sorting, scope, global-variables

I'm trying to sort an array into a new sorted array.

```js
const a = [25, 15, 30, 50, 45, 20];

let cheap = 0;
let ordered = [];

const listLength = a.length;

for (let atual = 0; atual < listLength; atual++) {
    Ordenador(a);
}

function Ordenador(arr){

    // let cheap = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if(arr[i] < arr[cheap]) {
            cheap = i;
        }
    }
    ordered.push(arr[cheap]);
    arr.splice(cheap,1);
}
```

If I make the `cheap` variable global, the new return array is

```js
[ 15, 20, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined ]
```

but when `cheap` variable is inside of the function it works as expected!

I don't understand why it doesn't work when the `cheap` variable in in the global scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because, in the loop, cheap changes to 0 in your local variable case and in the case of global one. It doesn't change to 0. Hence, you're getting undefined in your array

Comment: thanks for the response, but why doesn't work on the global space?

Comment: As i mentioned above, because when the loop starts it's not initalized to 0